# how is method reference working even when signature of apply method does not match

Tags: java, method-reference

I was learning `method reference` topic in `java8`. I learnt that **method reference** provide reference to already existing method (with similar argument types). But I want to know, how is the below code RUNNING successfully even when method arguments are different.

```
import java.util.function.*;


interface Sayable{
    String say();
}


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();

        System.out.println(test.doThis(Sayable::say));

    }

    private <T> T doThis(Function<Sayable,T> func) {
        SaySomething ra = new SaySomething();
        return func.apply(ra);
    }

}


class SaySomething implements Sayable{

    @Override
    public String say() {
        return "hi";
    }

}
```

If I am not wrong here `Sayable::say` will get to `Function<Sayable,T> func` argument of `doThis` method. But `say()` method has no argument yet how it gets referenced to `R apply(T)` method of `Function` interface. If `String say()` method is different than `R apply(T)` then how is `Sayable::say` not showing any error?

Comment: It's equivalent to `(Sayable s) -> s.say()`